# How To Count Higher High OREDR BY DATE MYSQL Table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am going through a project where I need to calculate higher high According to Time. below mention an Example of a Sample table

```
SYMBOL  CLOSE   DayNo   YearNo  Rank_No
TCS     2940     1        2021     8
TCS     3050.75  2        2021     7
TCS     3114.25  3        2021     4
TCS     3113.5   4        2021     5
TCS     3080.85  5        2021     6
TCS     3128     6        2021     3
TCS     3230     7        2021     1
TCS     3210     8        2021     2
```

In this above example table, the Rank_No column is showing the maximum price reached between mentioned dates. Now I want to Count each next row rank whether it's lower than the previous all rows or each next row is minimum above all rows. Like

```html
SYMBOL  Close     DayNo   YearNo  Rank_No  Count
TCS     2940        1      2021     8       NO
TCS     3050.75     2      2021     7       YES
TCS     3114.25     3      2021     4       YES
TCS     3113.5      4      2021     5       NO
TCS     3080.85     5      2021     6       NO
TCS     3128        6      2021     3       YES
TCS     3230        7      2021     1       YES
TCS     3210        8      2021     2       NO
```

So Each time the price closes higher than the past days. It should count yes.

Your support will be highly appreciated...Thanking You

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the Winwo function LAG for that

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tradesorder (
>   `SYMBOL` VARCHAR(3),
>   `CLOSE` FLOAT,
>   `DayNo` INTEGER,
>   `YearNo` INTEGER,
>   `Rank_No` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tradesorder
>   (`SYMBOL`, `CLOSE`, `DayNo`, `YearNo`, `Rank_No`)
> VALUES
>   ('TCS', '2940', '1', '2021', '8'),
>   ('TCS', '3050.75', '2', '2021', '7'),
>   ('TCS', '3114.25', '3', '2021', '4'),
>   ('TCS', '3113.5', '4', '2021', '5'),
>   ('TCS', '3080.85', '5', '2021', '6'),
>   ('TCS', '3128', '6', '2021', '3'),
>   ('TCS', '3230', '7', '2021', '1'),
>   ('TCS', '3210', '8', '2021', '2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `SYMBOL`, `CLOSE`, `DayNo`, `YearNo`, `Rank_No`,
> IF(`CLOSE` > LAG(`CLOSE`)  OVER (PARTITION BY `SYMBOL` ORDER BY  `YearNo` ASC,`DayNo`), 'YES','NO') as `Count`
> FROM tradesorder
> ```
>
> ```
> SYMBOL |   CLOSE | DayNo | YearNo | Rank_No | Count
> :----- | ------: | ----: | -----: | ------: | :----
> TCS    |    2940 |     1 |   2021 |       8 | NO   
> TCS    | 3050.75 |     2 |   2021 |       7 | YES  
> TCS    | 3114.25 |     3 |   2021 |       4 | YES  
> TCS    |  3113.5 |     4 |   2021 |       5 | NO   
> TCS    | 3080.85 |     5 |   2021 |       6 | NO   
> TCS    |    3128 |     6 |   2021 |       3 | YES  
> TCS    |    3230 |     7 |   2021 |       1 | YES  
> TCS    |    3210 |     8 |   2021 |       2 | NO
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cf8580fdef4796b957798f1e7d6fb2d)*

Comment: Just a typo `In MySQL 8+` not `In MySQL 9`

Comment: Yes MySQL 9 is a long way from being released thx